# Kotlin: using google-guava static methods as extensions

Tags: guava, kotlin

Is it possible to use existing java static methods as extensions from the box?

Lets consider `com.google.common.collect.Iterables.transform`. Now, because I don't know how to deal with this, to use proposed method as the extension, I have to write something like:

```
import com.google.common.collect.Iterables.transform

public fun <F, T> Iterable<F>.transform(function: Function<in F, out T>) : Iterable<T> {
    return transform(this, function);
}
```

So, after this I could use it with iterables:

```
Iterable<A> input;
Function<A, B> function;
Iterable<B> output = input.transform(function);
```

But I think that declaring extension myself is unnecessary. How to omit this declaration?

---

**Update**

My question has two main subquestions:

1. Is it possible to import existing (static) methods as extensions?

   No, for now it isn't possible.
2. How to reuse existing guava's `Function`s, e.g. to `transform` `Iterable`s?

   Instead of `transform` you should use `map` extension, as proposed in answers. To reuse `Function`s it is possible to use extension like this:

```
public fun <T, R> Function<T, R>.asFun(): (T) -> R
    = { input -> apply(input) };
```

Comment: Quick question, why are you needing `.transform` when we have `.flatMap`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't bring Guava's workarounds for Java into Kotlin. Such API is already a part of Kotlin runtime. So you can write:

```
val input = listOf(1,2,4,8)
val output = input.map { /*transform function*/ it + 1 }
```

http://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/map.html

All others you can easily discover in IDE's suggestions
[image]

Comment: The main reason I don't like to use `map`, is that it creates another collection. I couldn't find something like `view(transform: (T) -> R) for Iterable<T> in kotlin Iterable<R>`, and corresponding lambdas for `List`, `Map`, etc.

Comment: You can use Kotlin's Streams for that.

Comment: Kotlin "Streams" conflicted with Java 8 "Streams" so Kotlin renamed theirs to "Sequences". e.g. `input.asSquence().map { /*transform function*/ it + 1 }`

Comment: There is a big misconception that copying a collection into another on transform is less performant.  That is NOT always true, sometimes lazy processing is less performant.  Depends on size of the collection and if it can take advantage of CPU cache.